# Passing Value from Unbound Textbox on Subform to Bound Textbox on Main Form

Tags: subform

I'm updating a bound textbox on a main form from a textbox on the subform using the following code:

Public Sub CompletedAC_Click()
Me.CompletedAC = [Forms]![BingoUpload]![CompCount]
End Sub

While the subform is open when I click on the textbox and it does update; which is good and what I need. However I don't want to click on it I want it to update automatically when the subform updates. I've tried CompletedAC_Change() and AfterUpdate neither work.